# Using 'LIKE' operator with a subquery that returns multiple results

Tags: oracle, subquery, sql-like

Newbie to SQL. Kindly help.

I need to count number of records which have a pattern in one of the fields, for multiple patterns. I know how to do it for one pattern, but how do I get count of each pattern when there are multiple patterns coming from a subquery.
I am using Oracle. I will try to explain with an example.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TableA
WHERE 
TableA.comment LIKE '%world%';
```

Now this code will return the number of records which have 'world' anywhere in the TableA.comment field. My situation is, I have a 2nd query which has returns a list of patterns like 'world'.How do I get the count of each pattern ?

My end result should just be 2 columns, first column pattern, second column count_of_pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `like` to join the subquery to the table:

```
SELECT p.pattern, count(a.comment)
FROM (subquery here that returns "pattern"
     ) p left outer join
     TableA a
     on a.comment like '%'||p.pattern||'%'
group by p.pattern;
```

This assumes that the `pattern` does not have wildcard characters.  If it does, then you do not need to do the concatenation.

This also uses a `left outer join` so that all patterns will be returned, even with no match.