# Oracle subquery after like error

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE 1=1 and u.user_name LIKE 'A%'
```

It works as expected. But the following line results in an error message.

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE 1=1 and u.user_name LIKE (select '%arthur%' from dual)
```

The error message is the following:

```
ORA-00933 SQL Command not properly ended
```

I have tried to close the query with ";" but it is still gives the same error. What could cause this error?

Edit: I need LIKE and can't use IN, lets assume we have only one 'arthur' in the users database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 'LIKE' operator with a subquery that returns multiple results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049602/using-like-operator-with-a-subquery-that-returns-multiple-results)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 'abcd' LIKE (SELECT '%bc%' FRM DUAL);` works without error. How are you invoking that statement?

Comment: syntax seems to be correct, where are you trying to execute this statement?

Comment: What is the point of putting that subquery after `LIKE`?

Comment: @JohnHC The sub-query is only returning a single value.

Comment: What's wrong with `u.user_name LIKE '%arthur%'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query appears to be correct syntactically.  The subquery is a *scalar subquery*, which returns only one column and at most one row.

In general, you can use `LIKE` with a subquery using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE 1 = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM t
              WHERE u.user_name LIKE t.col
             );
```

If your actual query is more complicated, then this might solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried same query as per your,it worked fine.

SELECT * FROM employee e where 1=1 and e.name like (select '%abc%' from dual);